# Simple Jobs/Run scenario and parameters, refreshing, etc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

What I'm trying to accomplish:

1. A web page will present a list of jobs that can be run. For now they will run synchronously and I'll worry about asynchronous later.
2. When the user clicks run on a job, either a lightbox will show or all the run buttons will grey out with a message and a spinner indicating that the job is running. The job will be initiated via an ajax call, and when the web request returns, the state will be reset and an indication will be shown that the job is complete (success or fail).
3. I'd like to be able to visit a URL such as `/Jobs/Run/JobName` or `/Jobs/JobName/Run` to run a job. However, I don't think there's a need for a separate page per job to view or run a job, as it's perfectly adequate to list all the jobs and do the same action as if the user had clicked on one of them. (In a future scenario, there will likely be jobs plus a list of running jobs, and managing them all on one page makes more sense).

However, I have a few misgivings.

- If I use a URL like above, then once the job finishes and you run another job, the URL won't match the current action (it might show `/Jobs/Run/A` but would be running job B instead). Thus, I think it makes the most sense to, on a run request, redirect to `/Jobs` and inject the desired job in via javascript.
- If I just use an injected javascript value or snippet of code directly in the emitted HTML to cause the job to run, then the user navigates to another page and then presses the back button, won't the javascript run again? That is NOT desired.
- Also, I do try to avoid using the session unless it's absolutely necessary, due to how it can cause issues such as when an application eventually scales to multiple web servers and suddenly you have to come up with some distributed session management system or stop using sessions altogether and wish you hadn't done so in the first place. So is there an alternate way to achieve Get-Redirect-Get between the Run URL and the non-Run URL?
- I've considered using a cookie (but there's the session again). I've considered using a hash in the URL instead such as `/Jobs#Run/JobName` but this means adding complexity of parsing/watching the hash or pulling in a javascript library. The advantage of the hash is that the page can then remove the hash once the job is done running. (I also plan to warn about re-running a job if refresh is clicked while the job is still running, incomplete.) But then again, pages can also change the URL without triggering the browser to actually load anything (right? I'm not 100% sure on this), so maybe that's an answer.

And finally, I'm now reconsidering whether I should even allow a job to be run from a GET request, because the jobs can change data state, so it seems like *maybe* not best practice and I should only allow a POST. Am I just barking up the wrong tree at this point in my GET job-run thinking? Even so, I still have some of the same issues around Post-Redirect-Get and trying to avoid the session.

I'm sure the best path forward is super obvious and I'm just missing it. What do you suggest?

Comment: `localStorage` might be your answer. I like to think of it as a `cookie` on steroids. Nice thing is ... no session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my quick analysis:

First, I wouldn't do redirects at all. Redirects IMO create a program flow nightmare. Along time ago it was the only way but not anymore.

I would use a hash in the url. There are libraries and I found this article: [A modern JavaScript router in 100 lines](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/A-modern-JavaScript-router-in-100-lines-history-api-pushState-hash-url). The author even has a GitHub project here: https://github.com/krasimir/navigo. The are several advantages to this:

- You have a directly addressable action in the URL.
- You can change the
  action without a roundtrip to the server.
- Your "actions" use the
  router to trigger changes in the hash of the address. This means you
  only have to handle those actions one way. It won't matter if the
  user triggered the action via the URL or through a javascript
  funciton on the page.

To handle the problem of the user navigating backwards you can use `localStorage` to keep track of running jobs. In this way you won't restart a job until it's finished. This also sets the stage for running multiple jobs asynchronously.

Finally, if you keep track of the current jobs that are active in some way on the server, you can send that list at initial page load; update the `localStorage` and make decisions right away.

Comment: I like the advice to avoid redirects if possible. I think there still may be cases for them in some situations (of course), but local storage is definitely a good way to deal with certain kinds of redirects, especially combined with being able to rewrite the browser history from javascript to expunge an initial URL (in a post/redirect/get scenario). Keeping track of current jobs being active could be difficult as that requires making the back end asynchronous which I am avoiding for now.